# Text-decoration: none using table --having trouble

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

Although this may seem trivial to most of you, for some I can't get the `text-decoration:none` apply in a table cell as shown in the below.

What am I doing wrong with my css?

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated

```css
table{
  font-size: 50px;
}

table a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <p>Quote Master</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Text decoration seems to be working as per your code, there must be some other css conflict or some class being applied on your code.

Comment: Same here, the code is working fine. can you explain what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Sorry all, I phrased the wrong question: I was asking how to override the hyperlink color to its default and just a simple google search help me.

For those curious: 
a{
 color: inherit
}

Thanks for all who tried to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the black color, apply `color: inherit` to the anchor tag.

Generally **the color of the anchor tag is 'purple'(#0000EE;)**, if you see any where,
Eg: google search results all links consists purple color links.

If we apply `color: 'inherit'`, the parent's color will be applied to the anchor overriding the default color, if it also not black, you can explicitly declare `color: 'black'` to that anchor.

```css
table{
  font-size: 50px;
  }

table a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit
 }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <p>Quote Master</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Yep! I was asking the wrong question, but that's the answer.
Cheers

Comment: Your question is something correct, its the behavior of anchor tag that made you confused.